# VBA word / excel : Class_Initialize(), get property from Ribbon checkbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I cannot find example how to get property of Ribbon Checkbox (enabled / disabled) during initialize user class.  How call OnGetPressed of  Checkbox  in `sub Class_Initialize()`
Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more information. WHAT Class_Initialize? Is this really VBA or something else (VSTO)? Show us some relevant code, including the Ribbon definition.

Answer (score 0):

Question for VBA.

I have a class: AlScheme

```
Option Explicit
Private vClearPrg As Boolean

Public Property Get ClearPrg() As Boolean
  ClearPrg = vClearPrg
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Call SetOptions_OnGetPressed(xxxxxxxxx, vClearPrg)
End Sub
```

Module: MyRibbon

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyScheme As AlScheme
Public Rib As IRibbonUI

Public Sub AutoExec()
   Set oAppClass.oApp = Word.Application
End Sub

Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
  Set Rib = ribbon
End Sub

Sub SetOptions_OnGetPressed(ByRef control As IRibbonControl, ByRef pressed As Variant)

Set MyScheme = New AlScheme
pressed = New AlScheme.ClearPrg
End Sub
```

XML:
checkBox id="_clearFormat" label="Clear Prg" onAction="SetOptions" getPressed ="SetOptions_OnGetPressed"

How get property ClearPrg during initialize user class? (Marked xxxxxxxxx)
Or any other solution.

Thank you.